# How do I handle plain text HTTP Get response in Golang?

Tags: rest, http, go

I am making an HTTP GET request to an endpoint that returns a plain text response.

How do I grab the string of the plain text response?

My code looks like the following:

```golang
url := "http://someurl.com"

response, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer response.Body.Close()
responseString := //NOT SURE HOW TO GRAB THE PLAIN TEXT STRING
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Response of the body can be read using any method that could read data from incoming byte stream. Simplest of them is ReadAll function provided in ioutil package.

```
responseData,err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

It will give you API response in []byte. If response is plain text you can easily convert it into string using type conversion:

```
responseString := string(responseData)
```

And Check the result

```
fmt.Println(responseString)
```

**Sample Program:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    url := "http://country.io/capital.json"
    response, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    responseData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    responseString := string(responseData)

    fmt.Println(responseString)
}
```

Comment: If you get a web page with (for e.g) spanish/italian/etc. characters, you won't get a good result in conversion of `[]byte` to `string`. Exactly, characters such as `é`, `á`, etc. you will get � character. You need iterate the `responseData` and to concat every character. An optimized way would be [this](https://play.golang.org/p/IPKmytFOEd) ;-)

Comment: @Amd 's answer resolves the problem of Unicode text with same way my previous comment, however, I think better ;-)

Comment: @ToniVillena "spanish/italian/etc. characters, you won't get a good result in conversion of `[]byte` to `string`" — This is incorrect. If you have a valid UTF-8 byte slice, which you will if you io.ReadAll a UTF-8 encoded HTTP response, you can directly print convert `[]byte` to `string`. See [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/x7b2F1wI3j8). On the other hand, if you incorrectly/manually construct a byte slice like in [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/9GZ-J8a7iCv), then you will get �.

Answer (score 6):

Use `ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)`.

Also you may handle Unicode text using `bufio.NewScanner(response.Body)`
like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    response, err := http.Get("http://127.0.0.1")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(response.Body)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    for scanner.Scan() {
        buf.WriteString(scanner.Text())
    }
    fmt.Println(buf.String())
}
```

output:

```
*Hello World* B=µH *
```

Using this sample web server code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    body := "*Hello World* B=µH *"
    fmt.Fprint(w, body)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", ServeHTTP)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Amd for you answer! , I didn't know that way of to decode an bytes array of Unicode text to string, and for me was an headache... :-)

Comment: @ToniVillena  Thanks for encouraging

Comment: I don't think you need to read individual runes, like this answer does. See my reply to ToniVillena in Mayank Patel's answer.

Answer (score 5):

With `io.Copy` you read all bytes from an io.Reader, and write it to an io.Writer

```
resp, err := http.Get(server.URL + "/v1/ping")
if err != nil {
    t.Errorf("failed to execute GET request: %s", err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

var b bytes.Buffer
if _, err := io.Copy(&b, resp.Body); err != nil {
    t.Errorf("failed to copy response body: %s", err)
}

fmt.Println(b.String())
```