# How to make an HTTP request to get data from clickhouse database

Tags: database, go, clickhouse

I'm trying to make an HTTP request to get data from clickhouse database using  Go. I don't have too much experience with it and not sure how to get the returned value by the query

This is what I have:

```
reader := strings.NewReader("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM system.tables WHERE database = 'local' AND name = 'persons'")
request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost:8123", reader)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

client := &http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(request)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

fmt.Println("The answer is: ", resp.Body)
```

The expected output should be a number (1 means table exist and 0 means that doesn't exist) but I'm getting in `resp.Body` this output:

```
The answer is:  &{0xc4201741c0 {0 0} false <nil> 0x6a9bb0 0x6a9b20}
```

Any idea to get just the value of the query?

Comment: `resp.Body` isn't the response body; it's an `io.Reader`, from which you can read the response body.

Comment: Take a look at e.g. https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I handle plain text HTTP Get response in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807903/how-do-i-handle-plain-text-http-get-response-in-golang)

Answer (score 0):

I had to add an extra line

```
message, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

fmt.Println(string(message))
```

That helped me to get what I wanted.